# convert pil gif image to pygame surface without saving it on the disk

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, python-imaging-library, gif

I would like to get images from server side and display them on client side by pygame and not save each frame on disk. images are transferred using base64 encode and decode. when data is received from the other side it is decoded to PIL image. Then i can successfully save it to a temporary file ,open it with pygame and display it. however I would like to do it directly using image.tostring() but noting is displayed I am also noticed that when i save to temporary file pictures attributes are:
Surface(32x32x32 SW)

and when I do it directly:
Surface(32x32x8 SW)

thanks:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

import pygame
from PIL import  Image


def gif__to_string(filePath):
    gif_file = filePath
    content = base64.encodestring(open(gif_file, 'rb').read())

    return content


def string_to_gif(imageStr):
    gif_image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imageStr)))

    return gif_image


def show_gif_working(im):
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    pygame.init()
    width = 350;
    height = 400
    imageX = 200;  # x coordnate of image
    imageY = 30;  #
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    screen.fill(black)
    im.save('temp.gif')

    surface = pygame.image.load("temp.gif").convert()

    screen.blit(surface, (imageY, imageY))
    pygame.display.flip()


def show_gif_not_working(im):
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    pygame.init()
    width = 350;
    height = 400
    imageX = 200;  # x coordnate of image
    imageY = 30;  #
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    screen.fill(black)

    mode = im.mode
    size = im.size
    data = im.tostring()

    surface1 = pygame.image.fromstring(data, size, mode)

    screen.blit(surface1, (imageX, imageY))

    pygame.display.flip()


def main():
    content = gif__to_string('face5.gif')

    print content
    myImage = string_to_gif(content)
    # show_gif_working(myImage)
    show_gif_not_working(myImage)


main()
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727425/142637) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pygame.image.load[[1](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)] with a file-like object instead of a string?

You could pass a StringIO[[2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)] object instead of a file.

Comment: surface = pygame.image.load1(im).convert()  yealds error

Comment: surface = pygame.image.load1(im).convert()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load1'

Comment: The 1 and 2 you see are just links to the documentation. If you click on the link you will see, you can call load passing a file object instead of the path to the file. If you build a StringIO with the contents of the image and pass it to load it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem!

The code from the top of this thread works with jpg-files, but now with gif's.

The simple idea with:

```
myimage = Image.open("test.gif")
pyimage = pygame.image.load(myimage)
```

puts out an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 12, in  <module>
    pyimage = pygame.image.load(myimage)
TypeError: not a file object
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29866597)

Answer (score 0):

I use Python 3.7 with the function:
`pg.image.frombuffer()`, or `pg.image.fromstring()`

The details:

```
import PIL.Image as Image
import pygame as pg

gif = Image.open('file.gif')
for i in range(gif.n_frames):
    gif.seek(i)
    surf = pg.image.frombuffer(gif.tobytes(), gif.size, gif.mode)
```

`gif.seek(i)` is to locate the gif to a unique position,
and the `surf` the Surface object that you want.